# Unable to save Multiple dataframe into single csv ,Only last df is getting saved

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, selenium, csv

I am trying to scrape multiple tables from single webpage, but unable to save it to .csv file. only last table is getting saved below is the code, please suggest

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
import pandas as pd

base_url = 'https://uk.insight.com/en_GB/shop/product/2W1F2EA%23ABU/HEWLETT-PACKARD-(HP-INC)/2W1F2EA%23ABU/HP-ProBook-440-G8--14"--Core-i7-1165G7--16-GB-RAM--1-TB-SSD--UK/'
print('Opening Chrome Browser Automatically in 5 secs')
time.sleep(5)
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get(base_url)
df = pd.read_html(driver.page_source)
df2 = df[4:]
for table in df2:
    df = pd.DataFrame(table)
    df.to_csv('table.csv',index=False)
```

i am not aware how to save all dataframe into single .csv as per above only last df is getting saved.

Comment: Do you want to save each table to a separate csv file, or combine all the tables into one and save the combined table to one csv file?

Comment: i want to save all combined table to one csv

Comment: Do all the tables have the same number of column and the same column names?

Comment: Yes it has same number of columns but different column names

Comment: You could try creating a list before your loop, then appending each `df` to the list, then after the loop, call `pd.concat(df)` or `pd.concat(df, axis=1)`. Both of those two will return dataframes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the [Pandas .to_csv()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) documentation you can use the `mode` parameter to append data instead of overwrite. It is set to 'w' as default.

If you want to append data you can switch the mode to "a"

```
df.to_csv('table.csv', mode='a', index=False)
```

One thing to note is that is the column names will also be appended unless you set `header = False`

Here is a quick reproduceable example.

```
import uuid
import pandas as pd

dataframe = pd.DataFrame({
    "person_id": [str(uuid.uuid4())[:7] for _ in range(6)],
    "hours_worked": [38.5, 41.25, "35.0", 27.75, 22.25, -20.5],
    "wage_per_hour": [15.1, 15, 21.30, 17.5, 19.50, 25.50],
})


dataframe2 = pd.DataFrame({
    "person_id2": [str(uuid.uuid4())[:7] for _ in range(6)],
    "hours_worked2": [38.5, 41.25, "35.0", 27.75, 22.25, -20.5],
    "wage_per_hour2": [15.1, 15, 21.30, 17.5, 19.50, 25.50],
})

dataframe.to_csv('TEST.csv', mode='w', index=False)
dataframe2.to_csv('TEST.csv', mode='a', index = False, header=False)

print(pd.read_csv('TEST.csv'))
```

**OUTPUT**

```
   person_id  hours_worked  wage_per_hour
0    1aa66bc         38.50           15.1
1    b7abe05         41.25           15.0
2    15e1779         35.00           21.3
3    3c117d7         27.75           17.5
4    2e6494e         22.25           19.5
5    2a25e45        -20.50           25.5
6    b17d084         38.50           15.1
7    6ca361e         41.25           15.0
8    2cd18e4         35.00           21.3
9    9d120ff         27.75           17.5
10   a0b20d9         22.25           19.5
11   bf9a98d        -20.50           25.5
```

Comment: What if all the dataframe having same column name and I want to write them in a single csv file with non-repeated header?